# Replace leading apostrophe in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

could anyone advise me about the following?

In excel sheet, all cells of column (F), contain something like that.
'10+5+3
I need to convert it to equation by replacing apostrophe with equal sign.
=10+5+3
to make excel able to do the math.

Regards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, it's CSV, comma separated values and is an answer. Consider to remove your comment and place as an answer.

Comment: @fred_dot_u, thanks... too much contact with pharmacies, lately ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Though there might be a way to correct this *within* Excel, here is a simple work-around to test:

- In Excel, save the data as a CSV file (you might test using *tab*-separated values, rather than with **c**omma **s**eparated **v**alues).
- Open the .csv file in a text editor, such as [Kate](https://kate-editor.org/), Windows Notepad or [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).
- Search-and-replace single quote (') with the equal sign (=).
- Save the file with the same .csv extension.
- Open the file in Excel.

*Caveat:* If there is formatting or other Excel-specific feature in the original file, it will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

With a helper column.
Suppose that your data start in F1.

1. In the helper column enter:

   ="="&F1

and copy down to the end of data. In new Excel (365, 2021) you can fill the entire column at once, e.g.:

```
="="&F1:F10
```

2. Open the **Office Clipboard**, select and copy your formulas in the helper column and paste them back to the same place from the Office Clipboard. They should work as expected.

Variant solution
Step 2. may be replaced by two steps.
a) Copy formulas from the helper column and paste them back as values (using standard Windows Clipboard).
b) Use Text to Columns or Find/Replace (`Ctrl`+`H`, replace `=` by `=`) to make formulas work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your efforts
Unfortunately all answers do not work, but I could reach a suitable macro code, to do the job

```
Sub Replaceapostrophe()
For Each CELL In Selection
CELL.Value = "=" & CELL.Value
Next CELL
End Sub
```